# PHP preg replace only allow numbers

Tags: php, preg-replace

How can I modify this existing preg_replace to only allow numbers?

```
function __cleanData($c) 
{
    return preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", "",$c);
}
```

Answer (score 218, accepted):

I think you're saying you want to remove all non-numeric characters. If so, `\D` means "anything that isn't a digit":

```
preg_replace('/\D/', '', $c)
```

Answer (score 46):

Try this:

```
return preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "",$c);
```

Comment: In case you want to keep the dot for decimal numbers, it would be like this: ```return preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", "", $c);```

Answer (score 22):

This should do what you want:

```
preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "",$c);
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I want to keep number and '.' only

```
return preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", "",$c);
```