# Removing characters from data with php

Tags: php

In the database table that I use for this script, the rows have characters (like ".", "_") with numbers together. How can I remove the characters and only fetch the numbers from the table? 
The php code that I use:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>   
<body>     

<table class="tbnar">
<tr>
<th>Enex</th> 
<th>Snex</th>
</tr>

 <?php

  include ("config.php");

  $sql = "SELECT Enex, Snex FROM sntab";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

  $counter = 0;

   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
   {
        echo  "</td><td>". $row["Enex"] . "</td><td>" . $row["Snex"].   
            "</td></tr>";

            $counter++;
            if($counter % 33 == 0) { ?>
</table>

<table class="tbnar">
<tr>
<th>Enex</th> 
<th>Snex</th>
</tr>

 <?php }
    }
echo "</table>";

} else { echo "0 results"; }
$conn->close();
?>     
</table>               

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use mysql replace in select query itself - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html

Comment: @Manikandan Replace doesn't work like that and even if it did i don't think the op want to change the database values

Comment: This article may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688844/php-preg-replace-only-allow-numbers

Comment: @DimitrisFilippou I don't think so. In this case replace will work I feel. FYI please check this url once - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_mysql_replace

Comment: [OT] It's not a good practice to spit out html code with echo, consider using the short tags <?= and ?> and leave the html outside of php

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex to do this

```
echo  "</td><td>". preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/','',$row["Enex"]) . "</td><td>" . preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/','',$row["Snex"]).   
        "</td></tr>";
```

This regex will remove every non-numeric character.