# How To Remove a char from String in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, str-replace

I Want To Remove char ( = and " ) from string value ...

```
1 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1166 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        0 => "="12042205115""
      ]
    }
```

I Want To Get string from  ="12042205115" to 12042205115

Comment: You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688844/php-preg-replace-only-allow-numbers and probably put it in a `map` operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using a regular expression you can do that, try this one

```
$data= '="12042205115"'; preg_replace('/\D/', '', $data);
```